# DataTables built in search - disable "onKeyUp" trigger

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using js DataTables version 1.10.15, currently implementing search on my table (which gets it's data through ajax with server side processing).

I'm using the built-in search textbox (by adding `f` to the `dom` attribute in the constructor of the table).

The problem is that a search is triggered onKeyUp , I want to disable this feature and only trigger search when clicking a button or pressing enter in order to reduce the number of requests to my busy server.

Can that be done using dataTable built-in options or should I add my own button and textBox and in order to do it?

Thanks

Comment: There is no datatables `v1.0.15`.  Perhaps you meant [`v1.10.15`](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/)?

Comment: Anyhow, the answer you need is posted [**here**](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33368/jquery-datatable-serverside-search-on-enter).

Answer (score 8):

Ok, solved it, thanks to **user9263373** who send me to look at [this post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33368/jquery-datatable-serverside-search-on-enter). I will post the relevant part here for convenient:

Basically, what you need to do is to unbind the keyUp event of the built-in search box and then bind it again and trigger the event only if enter, i.e key code 13 is pressed.

```
var table = $('#emailsTable').......

    $('#emailsTable_filter input').unbind();
    $('#emailsTable_filter input').keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) /* if enter is pressed */ {
                table.search($(this).val()).draw();
            }
        });
```